# Docker Compose File Error: RubyonRail with Cassandra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cassandra, docker-compose

I followed the instructions at https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/ to create a Dockercompose file, except that instead of postgres I used Cassandra and created the following compose file:

seed1:

```
image: poklet/cassandra
environment:
   - DATACENTER=DC1
ports:
   - "9042:9042"
   - "9160:9160"
```

seed2:

```
image: poklet/cassandra
environment:
   - DATACENTER=DC1
ports:
   - "9042:9042"
   - "9160:9160"
```

nodedc1:

```
image: poklet/cassandra
environment:
   - DATACENTER=DC1
web:
build: .
command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
volumes:
  - .:/myapp
ports:
  - "3000:3000"
links:
  - nodedc1
```

Everything worked fine, except the db though one node of cassandra is created. I got the following error when I run `docker-compose` run web rails new .

```
--force --database=cassandra --skip-bundle.
```

Invalid value for `--database option`. Supported for preconfiguration are: mysql, oracle, postgresql, sqlite3, frontbase, ibm_db, sqlserver, jdbcmysql, jdbcsqlite3, jdbcpostgresql, jdbc.

How will I create a Docker compose file for my app with Cassandra db in this case ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like ruby on rails doesn't support cassandra by default? Maybe use a different ORM. Google tells me http://cequel.github.io/ is a thing.